# Using union() to combine historical and live data partitioned by different fields

Tags: apache-spark

I have a streaming ingest of sensor data where the data is being saved to S3 partitioned by time (year/month/day).  I'm calling this the *landing zone*.

I then have a periodic batch process to take the latest data from the landing zone and save it into another dataset in S3 that is partitioned by another set of keys.  This partitioning is for performance reasons; the users typically filter by the partition keys, so that when querying, the amount of data that needs to be retrieved from disk is minimised.  I'm calling this the *analytics zone*.

I now have a user that needs to query data across both landing and analytics zone, I.e. so they have the latest data available.

Is `union()` appropriate for joining datasets that have the same columns but are partitioned by different fields?  E.g.

```scala
// historical contains data up to but excluding Year=2018, Month=10, Day=1
// assetID is a partition field
historicalDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM historical WHERE assetID = 123")

// Year, Month and Day are partition fields
liveDF = spark.sql(
         """SELECT * FROM live 
            WHERE Year = 2018 AND Month = 10 AND Day = 1 AND assetID = 123""")

allDF = historicalDF.union(liveDF)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is union() appropriate for joining datasets that have the same columns but are partitioned by different fields?

Why wouldn't it be? Once  data is loaded with predicates, all opportunity for optimization through partition pruning (the main advantage of having partitioned table) is already used.

What you get is just a `DataFrame` as any other, with no partitioner set.Short of worrying about long lineages (and with such short pipeline, there is no reason to), `union` is just fine.